# Delaying a signal using LTC69942 - Some pulses missing at the output

Tags: clock, delay, timing

I want to delay a square wave by 1us to 30us. I am using a LTC6994-2 for this purpose.

Currently, I provided a delay of 1us.

What I can see is some pulses of the input are missing at the output. Please see my input/output waveform below:

[image]

Is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chip has a start-up time of 500 oscillator cycles after power-on reset and thus at the selected frequency it is very close to 0.5 ms.

Comment: I don't know what you want or need. I simply know that when power supply is applied to the chip, as it is configured now, it will take 0.5 ms to start working regardless of what you send or don't send to the input.

Comment: Thank you. My I/P frequency is 33khz.Do I need to increase my frequency.My intention is to delay the square wave by 1us to 30us.any suggestions

Comment: You asked why there are missing pulses at the beginning, I answered that it is normal as the chip has a startup time of 0.5ms no matter what. I don't know what you are doing and if you need to increase the frequency at the input, but whatever you do the chip still takes 0.5ms to be ready to process the input, whatever the input is.

Comment: I posted a new question with all my requirements.If you don't mind could you please check it .Thank you.