# Delaying a square wave by 1 us

Tags: digital-logic, analog, clock, delay, timing

This is a continuation of my previous [question - Delaying a signal using LTC69942 - Some pulses missing at the output.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/592517/delaying-a-signal-using-ltc69942-some-pulses-missing-at-the-output)

I have a square wave with below specifications:

[image]

I need to delay it by 1 us. I am expecting an output as shown below. The example is 1 us delay.

[image]

I used a LTC6994-2 to implement this but it has a startup time of 500 us so I am missing some pulses.
That is not what I want.

Could you please suggest some method to implement the same?

Comment: Just use a simple RC lowpass and a logic gate (buffer, etc). If you want it variable, use a pot instead of a fixed R.

Comment: Does it matter how you control the delay from 1 to 30 us? Analog , digital increments of 1us?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75,it does not matter

Comment: You're asking to delay the output by up to 30 us, and the period of the waveform is 30 us. Simple methods of delay cannot cope with that obvious overlap. That suggests you haven't thought this through, and you could actually do with a different method of generating the original square wave, what we call an X-Y problem - you are asking us 
 your idea of your solution, when you should be asking something deeper, outlining your problem, and asking the best way to solve it. What is the 1-30 us delay with respect to? Is this a simulator exercise, or do you want to build circuits in real life?

Comment: What purpose does this serve?

Comment: I need to build a real-life circuit. The current requirement is a delay by 1us only.I edited the question.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75,this is used for validating an AsIC

Comment: Delay by 1 us is easy. Delay by up to a whole period requires a different way of looking at the generation. You need to get your requirements sorted out before we can give you advice. What application is this for? It sounds like you are going about this the wrong way, and there's a far simpler way to get what you actually want, if only we knew what you actually want. For instance, do you need to generate two edges with a delay between them?

Comment: WHat are the tolerances on duty cycle rise time , voltage thresholds etc

Comment: You can't design anything without great specs

Comment: Is this an independent stimulus into the ASIC? Or is it a response to something the ASIC generates? Or neither of the above, if so, what?

Comment: @Neil_UK, *when you should be asking something deeper, outlining your problem* Excellent advice though you mean asking something more basic, less deep :-)

Comment: Currently, we are in the beginning stage now just I need an output square wave its's rising and falling edge have a constant delay of 1us compared to I/P

Comment: About 700 feet of coaxial cable would do it.

Comment: will purchase one and update you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is square, and the delay is less than half an input period, then a delay line like the LTC6994 seems overkill.

A simple RC delay at each transition, and some kind of comparator would do the trick:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2WHHC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

I initially considered using a logic gate instead of a comparator, but the switching thresholds for both regular 74HC/4000 gates and and their schmitt trigger versions are either too temperature dependent, or asymmetrical. So I settled on a comparator, where we can set the switching threshold precisely.

Ideally the comparator would be a push-pull output type, for symmetrical output rise and fall times. A good candidate for this application might be something like the [MAX941](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX941-MAX944-1292605.pdf).

With the trip-point set at half of the power supply (5V here) by R2 and R3, the delay \$T_D\$ between input and output transistions will be:

$$ T_D = R_1 \cdot C_1 \cdot ln(2) + T_{PROP}$$

\$T_{PROP}\$ is the propagation delay of the comparator, about 80ns for the MAX941. Simply choose R_1 and C_1 for \$T_D=1\mu s\$. The values I've shown are a little on the high side, but they get you close.

Comment: Thank you ..this is really working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cheap micro for that. FPGA or CPLD is to 'bulky' here in my opinion.

I can imagine a solution as followed:

- Little 8/10/12 pin device
- One ISR for the input, one pin for the output
- The rest can be used for configuration

You can design your software to take config from the IOs which can than be done on the board. Like binary coded delay in 100's of ns for example.

I dont know your timing requirements here but a 1us delay is nothing special for a low end 8 bit micro with minimal external components.

Software could be like:

```
SetupIo();
ReadConfigIo();
EnableIsr();
while(1);
```

You see: The micro has nothing to do, so the ISR jitter will be minimal.
If you dont use ISR you can handle your stuff in the loop.

Pros:

- Simple
- Flexible
- Reuseable
- Customizeable

Cons:

- More work than off-the-shelf
- Maybe higher unit cost in volume
- You need to flash the controller

May I suggest a [dirt cheap and simple 8 bit micro](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001615C.pdf)

This gives you 5 instructions to realize your `SetPinHigh()` - should be plenty, but you will have to do a little thinkering on codeflow to get everything fast enough.